# Show table names in MySQL database and the count of their records

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm working on the next step of the class assignment and I want to do a query where I pull the metadata from the database to list the tables in it then include the count of records in the tables. I have it where it kind of works but in the first half shown it only puts a number 1 where the count of records should go. In the second half (I'm doing this for testing purposes now and will only have the first half if I can get it to work) it prints out the number of records just fine but I have the table name hard coded in. I want it to be able to read in the table name from the metadata result then execute the query for the count of records. I am running this in netbeans with a MySQL database and am using the JDBC driver.

```
connect();

             try
                {     
                    String db = conn.getCatalog();
                    data.append("The current database " + db + " contains the following tables:\r\n");
                }
             catch(Exception err)
                {
                    System.out.print(err + "\r\n");
                }         

             try
                {   
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
                    rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
                        while (rs.next()) 
                        { 
                            String tbl = rs.getString(3);
                            System.out.print(tbl + "\r\n");
                            ResultSet ct = null;
                            ct = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM" + tbl);

                            while (ct.next())
                             {
                                 System.out.print(ct.getString(1) + "\r\n");
                                 data.append("Table \"" + rs.getString(3) + "\" contains " + ct.getString(1) + " records.\r\n");
                             }

                        }

                    data.append("\r\n");

                }
             catch(Exception err)
                 {
                     System.out.print(err + "\r\n");
                 }

             try
                 {
                     ResultSet ct = null;
                     ct = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer");
                     while (ct.next())
                     {
                         data.append(ct.getString(1) + "\r\n");
                     }

                     ResultSet pt = null;
                     pt = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product");
                     while (pt.next())
                     {
                         data.append(pt.getString(1) + "\r\n");
                     }

                 }

             catch(Exception err)
                 {
                     System.out.print(err + "\r\n");
                 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing and it works exactly as I wanted. I ended up using a prepared statement in the while loop to make it work.

```
connect();

             try
                {     
                    String db = conn.getCatalog();
                    data.append("The current database " + db + " contains the following tables:\r\n");
                }
             catch(Exception err)
                {
                    System.out.print(err + "\r\n");
                }         

             try
                {
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
                    rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);

                    while (rs.next()) 
                        { 
                            String tbl = rs.getString(3);
                            String query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tbl);   
                            PreparedStatement cnt = conn.prepareStatement(query);                         
                            ResultSet ct = cnt.executeQuery();
                            while (ct.next())
                            {
                                data.append("Table " + rs.getString(3) + " has " + ct.getString(1) + " records\r\n");
                            }  
                        }

                    data.append("\r\n");
                }

             catch(Exception err)
                {
                    System.out.print(err + "\r\n");
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

With following query you can query all tables with number of rows, date size, index size etc on a specific database.

```
SELECT concat(table_schema,'.',table_name) tables,
concat(round(table_rows),'') rows,
concat(round(data_length/(1024),2),'') data_size,
concat(round(index_length/(1024),2),'') index_size,
concat(round((data_length+index_length)/(1024),2),'') total_size,
round(index_length/data_length,2) index_data_ratio
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema like "%YOUR-DATABASE-NAME-HERE%"
ORDER BY rows DESC LIMIT 20;
```